# "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of "

Tags: android, json, kotlin

```
{"access_token": "IGQVJWZAmxOT3huRS02NHlxSWgybjVPd0g2Q2JUWGJOWER3Q0RlRzUzaDBiOTVjUUpOSTB4TUlYTRh4ZA0FvXzF1U0hFT3NBR1FEM2J4TmJPRUFDemhJVmdfbEItNEJ3VlZAPVXo2eVFiRGxJZAFBaUWtHeFZAsVnlFMUk3RU1N", "user_id": 17841415360011173}
```

This is my jsonstring from url**(I CHANGED THE TOKEN'S SOME LETTERS FOR PRIVACY")**

It cames in string and ı want to make it json

```
  var hhere= JSONObject(jsonstring)
```

It returns `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of` Error. Can anyone help?

Comment: The user_id is a unusually large number, bad implementation at server side.

Comment: The server side is Facebook/Instagram. is there any way to do it

Comment: I guess you use gson. I don't know what version you use but with the last "2.8.6" version it was parsed

Comment: The "user_id" should be a string and not a number. If you check out the documentation, the "id" is string-based. Hey, you discovered a facebook bug!

Comment: LOL.I should report it i think. So How can ı get the acces_token from tthis json

Answer (score 0):

```
val json = """{"access_token":"IGQVJWZAmxOT3huRS02NHlxSWgybjVPd0g2Q2JUWGJOWER3Q0RlRzUzaDBiOTVjUUpOSTB4TUlYTRh4ZA0FvXzF1U0hFT3NBR1FEM2J4TmJPRUFDemhJVmdfbEItNEJ3VlZAPVXo2eVFiRGxJZAFBaUWtHeFZAsVnlFMUk3RU1N","user_id": 17841415360011172}"""
val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)
```

It was normally parsed with `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6`